# Asymptotic behavior of unique integer partitions

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, integer-partitions

Okay, this is one of those questions that I'm sure has a very simple answer I'm missing, and I'd appreciate any push in the right direction.

Consider a very large integer $N$.  Stealing an example from Wikipedia, let $N=5$.  Clearly, there are a number of ways to write this as an integer partition:
$$P_5 = \{5, 4+1, 3+2, 3+1+1,2+2+1, 2+1+1+1,1+1+1+1+1\}$$
The cardinality of this set is given by the integer partition function, $|P_5| = p(5) = 7$.

It is known that there's a good asymptotic formula for $p(N)$ large $N$ (in my application, $N$ is greater than a billion, so it's very good indeed):

$$p(N)\approx \frac{1}{4N\sqrt3}e^{\pi \sqrt{\frac{2N}{3}}}$$

However, I'm not interested in finding the unrestricted partitions: I specifically want the number of partitions that do not repeat any number in the sum.  In the above example, the partitions I'd be interested in are $P_5^*=\{5,4+1,3+2\}$, and $|P^*_5| = p^*(5) =3$.  As another example, for $N=8$ you would have $P_8^*=\{8, 7+1,6+2,5+3,5+2+1,4+3+1\}$, $p^*(8) = 6$.

Obviously this grows quite a bit slower than $p(N)$, so here is my question: **Is there a large-N asymptotic formula for $p^*(N)$, and if so, what is it?**

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: There are some good results [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html) , specifically (14) for an asymptotic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The generating function of partitions with distinct parts is
>   \begin{align*}
>   \prod_{m=1}^\infty(1+z^m)&=1+z+z^2+2z^3+2z^4\\
> &\qquad+\color{blue}{3}z^5+4z^6+5z^7+\color{blue}{6}z^8+8z^9+\cdots
>   \end{align*}
>
> The coefficients $p^\star(N)$ are asymptotically equal to
>   \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{p^\star(N) \sim \frac{3^{3/4}}{12N^{3/4}}\exp\left(\pi\sqrt{\frac{N}{3}}\right)}
>   \end{align*}

See Figure I.9 of *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick.

Comment: (+1) for the epic reference...i was looking for something like this for a long time

Comment: @tired: This book is one of my treasures on my bookshelf. Even the reference list alone is superb. :-)

Comment: my goal for the next months (my rare spare time makes this long time scale necessary), to understand the asymptotics of $p(n)$ and related functions, now becomes very realistic since i already have a strong background in saddle point calculations. Thanks again!

Comment: @tired: You're welcome. Good decision. Have fun and much success in your studies.

Comment: As proved in Section 3 of Wilf's  (https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/PIMS/PIMSLectures.pdf), the GF for this sequence is $\prod_{m \geq 1} \frac{1}{(1-q^{2m+1})}$. Then we can express the GF for these partition functions by a ratio of the Dedekind eta function. This should let us apply circle method techniques to get these asymptotics, and in fact a better *exact* formula for this partition function variant. When I get around to doodling on this topic later, I will post a complete answer in this direction.

Comment: @MelVisoMartinez: The question is asking for the *asymptotic behaviour* of integer partitions. If you know a nice way to derive the asymptotic behaviour based upon your stated recurrence relations, you might want to provide an answer.