# How to calculate the number of subsets, elements of which add up to 25 in the set {1,2,3,4,5….,24,25} using generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

For example: one such subset would be:
{1,2,3,5,6,8} because 1+2+3+5+6+8=25

{25} would be another subset

I want to know how to count the total number of these in the total(2^25 total subsets)

I tried and got 1342177.36 when the answer should be a whole number.

Comment: What did you do with generating functions?

Comment: In general, this is equal to the number of partitions of $N$ into distinct parts, which is asymptotically
$$\frac{3^{3/4}}{12N^{3/4}}\exp\left(\pi\sqrt{\frac{N}{3}}\right)$$

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303741/asymptotic-behavior-of-unique-integer-partitions

Comment: How would you evaluate this for 25?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000009

Answer (score -1):

Take multiplication of polynomial ${(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)...(1+x^{25})}$, expand it and find the coefficient of the term ${x^{25}}$ , that is your number of subset that adds up to 25.

- you can test this generating function with lower value of n=3,which will be ${1+x+x^2+2x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6}$
- now subsets that will add up to 3 is ${\{3\}}$ and ${\{2,1}\}$, so coefficient in above polynomial is 2 before ${x^3}$
- same way subset that add up to 4 is $\{{3,1\}}$

Answer (score -2):

The number of distinct subsets which add up to 25 will be 142

We can refer to a smaller example to solve this question:

Consider $S(A)=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$

We can write this as a polynomial $p(x)=(1+x^1)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)(1+x^4)(1+x^5)$

{note:x is only used as a notation and not as a variable}

Expanding $p(x): 1+(x^1)+(x^2)+2(x^3)+3(x^4)+3(x^5)+3(x^6)+3(x^7)+3(x^8)+3(x^9)+(x^10)$

The power refers to the sum of the subsets and the number outside the bracket refers to the number of subsets whose elements add up to that number.
(note:1 is an empty set)

So if $S(B)=\{1,2,3,4,...,25\}$

$p(x)=1+(x^1)+(x^2)+2(x^3)+3(x^4)...+142(x^25)$

∴ Number of subsets in the set $\{1,2,3,4...,25\}$ that add up to $25$ is $142$

If you require furthur info on the topic, there is 3B1B video that delves into a topic that is very similar to this and was where I had gotten the answer from.

Reference:
[Olympiad level counting (Generating functions)](https://youtu.be/bOXCLR3Wric?si=lTvFX0qGT1DK3zku)