# Growth rate of the number of distinct partitions of n

Tags: asymptotics, integer-partitions

Using the language used on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Odd_parts_and_distinct_parts), is there a superpolynomial lower bound on q(n), the number of distinct partitions of a natural number n?

A reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Advice for a web query: "asymptotics" is a better keyword than "growth rate".

Comment: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1509/1509.08708.pdf, page 8

Comment: Thanks: asymptotics yields https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303741/asymptotic-behavior-of-unique-integer-partitions which answers my question